# JSLint issue in the code

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing this wierd two jslint issues for the below code

```
function hasSpecialChars(str){
return (/[~`@!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}()|\\":<>\?\s]/g).test(str);}
```

1. Unescape '/'
2. wrap regex patterns /regexp/ to disambiguate slash operator

I am trying to find the special characters in the string given.

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: It will be boolean either true or false

Comment: `I am trying to find the special characters in the string given.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use match function inorder to find all the special characters.

```
str.match(/[~`@!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]';,\/{}()|"\\:<>\?\s]/g)
```

And you must escape the forward slash.

To test for atleast one special char.

```
/[~`@!#$%^&*+=\-\[\]';,\/{}()|"\\:<>?\s]/.test(str)
```

or

```
/\W/.test(str)
```

Comment: I am still getting the JSLINT issue for wrap regex patterns /regexp/ to disambiguate slash operator when i use this /\W/.test(str)